# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adj_parameter' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

My `train_test` function

```
def train_test(data_folder, view_list, num_class,
               lr_e_pretrain, lr_e, lr_c, 
               num_epoch_pretrain, num_epoch):
    test_inverval = 50
    num_view = len(view_list)
    dim_hvcdn = pow(num_class,num_view)
    data_tr_list, data_trte_list, trte_idx, labels_trte = prepare_trte_data(data_folder, view_list)
    labels_tr_tensor = torch.LongTensor(labels_trte[trte_idx["tr"]])
    onehot_labels_tr_tensor = one_hot_tensor(labels_tr_tensor, num_class)
    sample_weight_tr = cal_sample_weight(labels_trte[trte_idx["tr"]], num_class)
    sample_weight_tr = torch.FloatTensor(sample_weight_tr)
    if cuda:
        labels_tr_tensor = labels_tr_tensor.cuda()
        onehot_labels_tr_tensor = onehot_labels_tr_tensor.cuda()
        sample_weight_tr = sample_weight_tr.cuda()
    adj_tr_list, adj_te_list = gen_trte_adj_mat(data_tr_list, data_trte_list, trte_idx, adj_parameter)
...
```

Calling `train_test` function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    data_folder = '../KIRP'
    view_list = [1,2,3]
    num_epoch_pretrain = 500
    num_epoch = 2500
    lr_e_pretrain = 1e-3
    lr_e = 5e-4
    lr_c = 1e-3
    
    if data_folder == 'KIRP':
        num_class = 4
    
    train_test(data_folder, view_list, num_class,
               lr_e_pretrain, lr_e, lr_c, 
               num_epoch_pretrain, num_epoch)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
     10 if data_folder == 'KIRP':
     11     num_class = 4
---> 13 train_test(data_folder, view_list, num_class,
     14            lr_e_pretrain, lr_e, lr_c, 
     15            num_epoch_pretrain, num_epoch)

File ~/MOGONET/train_test.py:128, in train_test(data_folder, view_list, num_class, lr_e_pretrain, lr_e, lr_c, num_epoch_pretrain, num_epoch)
    126     onehot_labels_tr_tensor = onehot_labels_tr_tensor.cuda()
    127     sample_weight_tr = sample_weight_tr.cuda()
--> 128 adj_tr_list, adj_te_list = gen_trte_adj_mat(data_tr_list, data_trte_list, trte_idx, adj_parameter)
    129 dim_list = [x.shape[1] for x in data_tr_list]
    130 model_dict = init_model_dict(num_view, num_class, dim_list, dim_he_list, dim_hvcdn)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adj_parameter' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of `adj_parameter` in your code (aside from the call). Where did you define it? Is there more code? Please show all of it.

Comment: @decorator-factory It's at the end of line 128 in the error, but it is never defined, hence the error.

Comment: @melolilili You're probably defining `adj_parameter` later in the function, but at this point it's not defined, hence the error. If you want to change a global variable, you need to use the `global` keyword.